# datetime.utc() doesn't give the correct value when run on Azure function app

Tags: python, linux, azure-functions

I am using a Function app on Azure with Linux OS using Python to make an API call. What I am doing is that I make the API call and drop the JSON file into a path in Storage account. I am trying to use `datetime.utcnow()` to get the current date and time and use it in the path.

When I run my function app locally, everything seems fine, and it gives today's correct date. But when I run on the Azure portal and Azure data factory, it doesn't provide the correct date; instead, it gives the same date as it was run locally on my system.

It's confusing for me, and I haven't got a solution for it yet.

```
ISOcurrentTime = str(datetime.now(timezone.utc).isoformat())
currentDate = str(datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Comment: Has the Function App been set to use an explicit timezone? You can do so by adding the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` App setting. See: [How do I set the server time zone for my web app?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-configuration-and-management#how-do-i-set-the-server-time-zone-for-my-web-app-).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, as UTC time is the same, regardless where code is run. If you're asking for current UTC time locally, and also somewhere else in the world, at roughly the same time, you'd get roughly the same timestamp.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, there's a difference between `datetime.utcnow()` and `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` in Python. I think one does take daylight savings time into account, where the other one doesn't. Anyhow: nice that it worked!

Comment: @rickvdbosch thanks for your response. I just noticed it is not working and I have made a mistake.  Although I have added WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE and set it to UTC, I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the servers timezone?

- Open terminal and connect to azure instance
- Use 'timedatectl' to check timezone on the azure server
- Then 'sudo timedatectl set-timezone <your_time_zone>'

Ref: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-or-change-timezone-in-linux/